# Rendering a component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am trying to render a component but I get the error: property or method 
"joke" is not defined in is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. I am using the dad jokes api to get data via the axios http library. Here is my code:

```js
var joke = Vue.component('joke', {
  template: '#joke',
  data() {
    return {
      jokes: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search', {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        params: {
          limit: 30
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.jokes = response.data.results;
      });
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#main'
});
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>vue Dad JOkes</title>
    <!--styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--scripts-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <joke></joke>
    </div>
    <template id="joke">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="joke in jokes"></li>
        <p>{{joke.joke}}</p>
      </ul>

    </template>


    <script src = "app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
 
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple issue with the html, you had ended the `</li>` before using `{{joke}}`

Change

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="joke in jokes"></li>
  <p>{{joke.joke}}</p>
</ul>
```

to

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="joke in jokes">
    <p>{{joke.joke}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's your working example:

```js
var joke = Vue.component('joke', {
  template: '#joke',
  data() {
    return {
      jokes: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search', {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        params: {
          limit: 30
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.jokes = response.data.results;
      });
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#main'
});
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>vue Dad JOkes</title>
    <!--styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--scripts-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <joke></joke>
    </div>
    <template id="joke">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="joke in jokes">
          <p>{{joke.joke}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </template>


    <script src = "app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
 
  </html>
```